# UIScrollView scrolling using a gesture on the overlaid view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Consider the view hierarchy in the figure below:

[image]

`OverlayView` is simply a control view that has some custom controls on it. It also has multiple tap/swipe gesture recognizers. The `ScrollView` is the scroll view that needs to be scrolled based on the interactions with `OverlayView`. The `OverlayView` has the same frame as that of the `ScrollView`.

I need a way to add some kind of swipe/pan gesture setup configured for the `OverlayView` such that I can scroll the underlying `ScrollView` as if I am interacting with it.

There seems to be two different approaches:

1. Recognize the gesture on the `OverlayView` and pass it to `ScrollView`. But I am unsure what gestures to use and how to make `ScrollView` interact with them.
2. Ignore all the touches on the `OverlayView` unless they are on the controls. Pass these touches to the underlying `ScrollView`. This seems like the easier approach; but I am not sure how to proceed with this either.

Does anybody have any kind of sample code for some project or a similar exercise they worked on before? If not, any pointers whatsoever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 is what I was going to recommend. There is a method you can override called `hitTest:withEvent:` on `UIView`.

You return a view from it. So if the touch needs to go through to the scroll view then return the scroll view. Else return self.

Comment: That is pretty cool. It does exactly what I wanted. However there is a small caveat. Say I wanted to recognize a pan gesture on the `OverlayView`. How would I do that using the same `hitTest:withEvent:` API?.

Comment: I mean surely it cannot be done with `hitTest:withEvent` but just wondering if there are other APIs that could be interfaced here.